# cordova no reconoce codigo php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cordova, apache-cordova

Hola nado liado intentando ejecutar ajax desde jquery en la app que estoy haciendo con cordova pero resulta que si la ejecuto desde el xampp (estando encendido) funciona pero ejecuto la app directamente desde el comando "cordova run browser" o "cordova run android" en las 2 plataformas me tira el siguiente mensaje[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y claro la verdad es que no se por que si lo abro desde xampp funciona y desde el propio comando de cordova no, buscando he creido entender que mi aplicacion de cordova no tiene php dentro del proyecto por lo cual no lo ejecuta y tna solo me devuelve el propio codigo en vez del resultado de su ejecucion
Y el problema que tengo reside en que no se como puedo hacer para que me reconozca php la app pues desde web si lo hago con xampp va bien pero luego en android no me deja de ninguna forma, os dejo aqui los codigo de los scripts y demas por si se me hubiera pasado algo

```
<?php
include 'aconexion.php';
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as usuarios FROM `bm_usuarios` WHERE `usuario`='".$_GET["usuario"]."' and `pass`='".$_GET["pass"]."';";
$conexion->query($query);
$resultado=$conexion->query($query);
if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
    echo 'true';
}
$conexion->close();
```

este es el codigo del php

```
$(function () {
    $('#login').on('click', function () {
        let usuario=$('#username').val();
        let pass=$('#password').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "php/checkIN.php",
            data: {usuario:usuario,pass:pass},
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

y este el de jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;script-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com  https://code.jquery.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com 'unsafe-inline';">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
  <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m8 l4 offset-m2 offset-l4">
        <div class="card">

          <div class="card-action teal lighten-1 white-text">
            <h3>BasketMatch</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="card-content">
            <div class="form-field">
              <label for="username">Usuario</label>
              <input type="text" id="username">
            </div><br>

            <div class="form-field">
              <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
              <input type="password" id="password">
            </div><br>

            <div class="form-field">
              <button class="btn-large waves-effect waves-dark" style="width:100%;" id="login">Entrar</button>
            </div><br>

            <div class="form-field">
              <a href="#">Registrarse</a>
            </div><br>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

y este ultimo el del index.html, lo dicho todo funciona pero no reconoce php cuando lo ejecuto fuera de xampp con los comandos de cordova

Comment: Es importante que comprendas una cosa: Javascript (y jQuery, que no es otra cosa que una librería basada en Javascript) trabajan **del lado del cliente**, mientras que PHP trabaja **del lado del servidor**. Ajax por su parte, permite la comunicación entre cliente y servidor. Por tanto, no tiene ningún sentido querer hacer funcionar código PHP directamente desde el cliente. En la url de Ajax es dónde debes indicar el script PHP que quieres que se ejecute del lado del servidor, recibir los datos y trabajarlos. Revisa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30636828/5587982) y sus respuestas.

Comment: muy bien lo entiendo perfectamente pues no es el primer proyecto que hago de esta forma y todos han funcionado a la perfeccion, el caso es que con cordova no funciona y no se por que @A.Cedano

Comment: si abro xamp funciona pero si uso el propio servidor que me ofrece cordova no funciona, y la base de datos es un servicio online que tengo con el resto de aplicaciones que he hecho con la misma mecanica y han funcionado perfectamente

Comment: cambia `url: "php/checkIN.php",` por una url completa q apunte al xamp

Comment: @aloMalbarez no entiendo como hacer eso que me dices

Comment: Yo no uso Cordova, pero el error que tienes es típico: en tu entorno no hay ningún intérprete PHP (por eso reconoce el script PHP como texto). Sobre la forma de hacer funcionar entorno de servidor en Cordova exactamente no podría decirte cómo hacerlo porque no tengo ni idea de cómo funciona ese framework.

Comment: @A.Cedano si a ver si la cosa es que eso ya lo se yo, lo que quiero saber es como hacer que funcione por que precisamente lo de que no tengo el interprete en el entorno lo se pero no se como anadirlo

Comment: si xamp está en `127.0.0.1`  ... `url: "http://127.0.0.1/php/checkIN.php"` si está en otra ip o en un dominio le cambias acorde.

Comment: @aloMalbarez no funciona pero ni de broma, es normal es que me da un error de que si intento acceder asi no existe ni el archivo checkIN.php ni el servidor de apache, incluso si cambio por localhost tampoco

Comment: Cordova genera aplicaciones a partir de html y javascript, no entiende php. Si bien es posible incluir un interprete php en una aplicación javascript ( via wasm ) lo mas conveniente es escribir el código necesario en javascript. Si la app necesita de datos generados o consultas del tipo login que dependen de un servidor, la forma es montar ese código php en un servidor que soporte php ( apache+mod_php o fastcgi ) y lo accedes con la url completa: `http(s)://dominio-o-ip/ruta-del-script` de la otra manera Cordova lo va a cargar y mostrar como archivo "local" (file://) y en este caso de texto.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que Cordova no está hecho para lo que estás intentando implementar. Tu problema es que estás intentando meter 2 aplicaciones en la misma. Tienes que entender que todo tu codigo PHP se está ejecutando en el servidor (vease XAMPP o lo que sea que uses para programar) y tu codigo HTML y Javascript se está ejecutando en el cliente, en este caso el navegador web. Tu problema es que Cordova solamente está pensado para ejecutar codigo de cliente. Deberías reescribir tu código a cierto punto en el que se comunique con el backend.